# How to open video, audio and image on secondaryActivity in android

Tags: android, listview, video, media, internal

I'm a new student on Android. I'm able to fetch an xml from website to display text along with thumbnail in a listview. i'm able to show the item with default application. It mostly opens browser or media plyaer, But i want to show the content within application in secondary activity. It should detect type of media from  tag from xml and display it on secondary activity using related module/class. I dont know how to add more activity and opening different media types internally. Below is the code i'm using now. Please guide me with keeping in mind that i'm a total newbie.  Thanks in advance.

xml looks like:

```
<items count="1">
  <item>
     <title>This is title no 1</title>
     <description>this is description</description>
     <type>mp3, image, video</type>
     <date>date of item</date>
     <thumb>url of an thumbnail</thumb>
     <url>url to play item from</url>
  </item>
</items>
```

//listview click code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
 String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc)).getText().toString();
 String type = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type)).getText().toString();
 String cTime = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time)).getText().toString();


 Element e = (Element) nl.item(position);  //using final var to get previously declared xmls
 String imageurl = parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL);  
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(imageurl))); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to go through INTENT Apis....they help in switching from one activity to other.....Secondly, When you are trying to play a media file, the Android OS detects the media type and selects the available applications to play that file from your device. It automatically intents from your app to the media player.Provided you have done the parsing of the xml fine. If there are no applications present that can present your file or say, if your device does not support a particular media type(say mp4,wmv, flv etc), it will throw you an error, media cannot be played as its not supported.

"It mostly opens browser or media plyaer, But i want to show the content within application in secondary activity"

This is what I mentioned previously. If you want the media to play your file from your application, then probably you should write your own media player class to which you can pass the intent